# How can I set an Angular component as content for GridStack widget?

Tags: angular, gridstack

I am using [GridStack](https://gridstackjs.com) ([NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gridstack)) to build a dashboard in my Angular project. I want to dynamically set Angular components as GridStack widgets. I currently trying it this way, which doesn't work:

**widget.component.ts**

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-widget',
  template: '<span>Widget (Angular Component)</span>',
})
export class WidgetComponent {}
```

**demo.component.ts**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { GridStack } from 'gridstack';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-demo',
  template: '<div class="grid-stack"></div>',
})
export class DemoComponent implements OnInit {
  ngOnInit() {
    const grid = GridStack.init();
    grid.load([
      {
        content: '<app-widget />',
      },
      { content: '<span>Widget (Native)</span>' },
    ]);
  }
}
```

This results in:
[image: Browser screenshot incl. DOM]

Of course, the browser doesn't know how to render `<app-widget />`. So, `<app-widget />` should be somehow pre-rendered here, in order to work. I tried it with *DomSanitizer (from @angular/platform-browser)* but I get the same result.

**The question is:** Does anybody know a way of setting an Angular component as content in a GridStack widget within code?

Thanks!

Comment: This is how I tried it with _DomSanitizer_:
`{content: this.domSanitizer.sanitize(SecurityContext.HTML, this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml('<app-widget />'))!}`

Comment: When you add `<app-widget />` with GridStack it doesn't actually add Angular components, only html tags with that name. You might need to let Angular generate component. Take a look at this https://github.com/gridstack/gridstack.js/pull/1824

Comment: @AviadP. You mean I should consider using [angular-gridster2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-gridster2)? Wasn't aware of this, to be honest. I will definitely try it out. Many thanks!

Comment: Whenever someone asks a question about a library which is not suited for angular, the first thing I search for is if someone already created an angular adaptation - it's the most straightforward "non-wheel-reinventing" way